# The transmission of color using sockets in C#

Tags: c#, sockets, colors

I am coding a program like DrawSomething. But I don't know how to transfer the attribution of drawpen of color.

I have a draw client and a guess client. When draw client changes the pen color, how to inform the guess client and draw diagram in the new color.

I want to know the client or the form about  how to read a new color using sockets and the type of color in transmission, string or RGB?

I am using this code. I consider it to be string, then I could using ptp protocol to transfer and it would be shown at the other end of client(guess client).

```
    public Color _drawPenColor = Color.Red;
    public int _drawPenWidth = 10;        
    ClientSendPtPPacket("DRAW-" + e.X.ToString() + "-" + e.Y.ToString() + "-" 
                                + _drawPenWidth.ToString() + "-" 
                                + _drawPenColor.ToString(),
                                opponentIP, opponentPort);
```

I have got the packets and the one of packets is that "**Draw-150-234(postion)-10(width)-Color [red]**".

And if I use color palette to change the color, it will be that "**Draw-150-234-10-Color [A=255, R=45, G=28, B=45]**".
IP and Port are ignored.

So my question is that how to get a new color.

PS:ClientSendPtPPacket Class

```
private void ClientSendPtPPacket(string content, IPAddress toIp, int toPort)
    {
        try
        {
            if (_socketClient != null && _socketClient.Connected == true)
            {
                string sendPacket = _localIP.ToString() + "-" + _localPort.ToString() + "-" +
                    toIp.ToString() + "-" + toPort.ToString() + "-" + content;
                Byte[] bytePacket = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(sendPacket);
                _socketClient.Send(bytePacket);
            }

        }
        catch (Exception excep)
        {

        }
    }
```

Comment: your question is unclear. What do mean with "So my question is that how to get a new color." ? In fact, why did you put network related code if you are questioning about color manipulation ?

Comment: I have a draw client and a guess client. When draw client changes the pen color, how to inform the guess client and draw diagram in the new color.

Comment: You mean the network related to code is useless. I think so. However, I use it to show you about how I transfer the Color code. Accurately, I want to know the client or the form about  how to read a new color using sockets and the type of color in transmission, string or RGB?

Comment: I have found a solution to this problem, but I couldn't solve it perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this problem by myself. I used [toAgrb()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev10.query?appId=Dev10IDEF1&l=ZH-CN&k=k%28SYSTEM.DRAWING.COLOR.TOARGB%29;k%28TargetFrameworkMoniker-%22.NETFRAMEWORK,VERSION=V3.5%22%29;k%28DevLang-CSHARP%29&rd=true) and [FromAgrb()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/library/system.drawing.color.fromargb%28v=vs.90%29) methods.

ToArgb() is used to show the number of color and the FromArgb() is used to get the number of color. So that, my guess client would know the color that the draw client have been using even draw client have changed its color.

But I could just use ToAgrb() and FromArgb() in the type of string.

My example is that:

```
        public Color ColorChange(string _color)
    {
        Color _newColor = new Color();
        switch (_color)
        {
            case "Red": _newColor = Color.FromArgb(Color.Red.ToArgb()); break;
            case "Orange": _newColor = Color.FromArgb(Color.Red.ToArgb()); break;
            case "Yellow": _newColor = Color.FromArgb(Color.Yellow.ToArgb()); break;
            case "GreenYellow": _newColor = Color.FromArgb(Color.GreenYellow.ToArgb()); break;
            case "DeepSkyBlue": _newColor = Color.FromArgb(Color.DeepSkyBlue.ToArgb()); break; 
            case "DarkBlue": _newColor = Color.FromArgb(Color.DarkBlue.ToArgb()); break;
            case "Purple": _newColor = Color.FromArgb(Color.Purple.ToArgb()); break;
            case "Black": _newColor = Color.FromArgb(Color.Black.ToArgb()); break;
            case "Gray": _newColor = Color.FromArgb(Color.Gray.ToArgb()); break;
            case "White": _newColor = Color.FromArgb(Color.White.ToArgb()); break;
        }
        return _newColor;
    }
```

Comment: You can replace that whole method with `Color _newColor = Color.FromName(_color);`